# JRadioButton in JPopupMenu does not close the menu after selecting

Tags: java, swing

With the above code i want to close the popup right after click on one of the radio buttons but the popup stays open.

Is there something build-in in swing or must i call actionPeformed and close the popup explicity ?

```
public class NewClass extends JFrame {

    NewClass() {
        setSize(100,100);

        JPopupMenu pop = new JPopupMenu();

        JRadioButton log1 = new JRadioButton("Level 1");
        pop.add(log1);

        JRadioButton log2 = new JRadioButton("Level 2");
        pop.add(log2);

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        add(p);
        p.setComponentPopupMenu(pop);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new NewClass().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at [JRadioButton](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)#[addItemListener()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#itemListener) and check if [ButtonGroup](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/buttongroup.html) is usefull in your case

EDIT:

```
Is there something build-in in swing or must i call actionPeformed and 
close the popup explicity ?
```

I don't know..., good question, but if you adds `JRadioButton` to the `JMenuItem` then is build-in look [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JRadioButtonMenuItem.html)

Comment: JRadioButtonMenuItem thats it ! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would have added actionlisteners on the buttons so when you press a button you then use:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    pop.setVisible(false);
    pop.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to use ActionListeners?